# How do I add a delay in to this image rotator?

Tags: jquery, slider, delay

Wanting the rotator to hold on the image for 4secs before moving on to the fade out animation. I've tried entering in .delay to numerous locations but I just can't figure out where it would go. Know only a little about jquery.

```
/* image rotator */
function changeImg(){
$('.photogallery').animate({opacity: 0}, 3000, function(){
$(this).css('background','url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +') ',);

}).animate({opacity: 1}, 3000);
}

});
```

Comment: wherever you have used 3000, it is animation delay only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: Do you have working code as is? Are you trying to create your own jQuery Slider? If so, please post the rest of the code (HTML & CSS)so we can get a better idea of what is going on. If you are using a jQuery plugin please state which one you are using.

Comment: @Nils that is incorrect. The 3000 the author stated above refers to the duration or speed of the animation (see official API documentation here - http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Have you considered [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)?

Comment: Yup, that's animation duration not delay. He wants delay before animation not during animation. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use the method you have currently, you would put `.delay()` before your initial call to `.animate()`. However, this would assume you are calling this method multiple times in succession.

```
$('.photogallery').delay(4000).animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 3000, function () {
    $(this).css('background', 'url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +')';
}).animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 3000);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z8fyZ/)**

If you want the method to self-trigger the next iteration, you could recursively call `changeImg` at the end of the animation execution. Although this rotates the images, utilizing recursion for endless loops often creates issues in browsers.

```
$('.photogallery').delay(4000).animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 3000, function () {
    $(this).css('background', 'url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +')';
    colorIndex++;
}).animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 3000, changeImg);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z8fyZ/2/)**

The preferred method would likely be to use `window.setInterval` to set a length of time between when the browser calls the method. You will have to play with the timing since it does not respect the animation delays occurring within the method. To get around this easily, I simply called it once before scheduling the with `setInterval`.

```
changeImg();
window.setInterval(changeImg, 4000);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z8fyZ/3/)**

Comment: @bradley Glad this helped. Please see my latest update. The recursive method I added will often cause issues in browsers so I would suggest the final option if you want a continually running method.

Comment: Ruben would it be possible to get your email? Could use some input on a site I'm doing.

Comment: @bradley Sorry, I'm not available for personal contact. I would suggest continuing to use SO as you work on your project and run into issues that you have trouble resolving. You have the added benefit of multiple people in the community becoming involved to help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Okay, no worries. How would I go about creating more of an overlay transition as appose to a fadein, fadeout? Also is there a way to have this start immediately instead of having a delay at the front?

Comment: @bradley Please create a new question if you have further issues you are trying to work through. I highly suggest trying a few things first and describing your attempts along with your expected results in your question. The community as a whole is more responsive when you show prior effort with existing code and demos.